# How to read roles from database instead of web config in Role-Based Authorization asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, role-base-authorization

We are working with an old designed system that is Role-Based and reads users roles from `webconfig` as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/UserMgmt/login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/Transaction/Index" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
</authentication>
     <authorization>    
           <allow roles="Admin" />  
           <allow roles="VicePres" />      
           <deny users="*"/>    
      </authorization>
```

I'm looking for a way to **remove roles** from `webconfig` and just have them in my database table.
I know it is somehow related to `IPrincipal` and `IsInRole` method, but after hours of googling could not wrap my head around that.

Where exactly `webconfig` roles are bind to security context and how should I change it?

Base on Microsoft article:

> When using role-based URL authorization rules the RolePrincipal's
> IsInRole method will be called on every request to a page that is
> protected by the role-based URL authorization rules

I've implemented `IsInRole` and its looking for roles in database query object and working fine, but when roles are removed from `Web Config`, user login is failed.

Comment: I'm reading roles from database but it seems required to be in weconfig too.

Comment: I think it is UrlAuthorizationModule that is calling IsInRole method and we need to change it.